# Can a SQUID perform real time measurements of a slow varying magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics

It is well known that a [SQUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID) can detect an extremely small magnetic flux.

What if the flux is time-dependent? E.g. a slow varying sinusoidal magnetic flux

$$\Phi=\Phi_0\sin(\omega t).$$

Can I still perform a real time measurement of the slow varying flux considering the induced EMF?

By "slow" I mean $\omega$ is smaller than Josephson frequency (AC Josephson effect due to the EMF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar to that in a labs course once, where the flux was temperature-dependent and the temperature was time-dependent. However, ‘my’ rate of change was *very* slow (a few hours for a temperature change from 2 K to 300 K with an associated flux change of maybe 500%), so I don’t know how well this applies to your experiment.

Once I get home I can have a look at the data we collected back then to tell the exact times and rates of flux change.